# Hide div until scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make it so that when I'm at the top of my page the `<DIV>` is invisible but whenever I scroll to it, it pops up with a link right back to the top of the page. Would it be easier to use JavaScript or is there a way to do it with just HTML?

Comment: Looks like you want to create an initially hidden "Back to top button" and there's plenty of questions/answers covering that part.

Comment: i already have the back to the top link, i'm attempting to figure out how to make it visible upon scroll instead of always visible using position: fixed.

Comment: You cannot do this with JUST HTML and CSS... Javascript needs to be used to determine the page has been scrolled.

Comment: SHow what have you tried so far, so we can see what you don't understand and where you left.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well there is no way (I know of) to do this without Javascript.

Assuming HTML like this:

```
<button id="top">Top</button>
```

you can use the following code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() { // when the page is scrolled run this
    if($(this).scrollTop() != 0) { // if you're NOT at the top
        $('#top').fadeIn("fast"); // fade in
    } else { // else
        $('#top').fadeOut("fast"); // fade out
    }
});

$('#top').click(function() { // when the button is clicked
    $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:0},500); // return to the top with a nice animation
});
```

You can still use "position:fixed" here because without visibility the user cannot see or click it.

Comment: i tried this but it only seems to stick the top right at the very top, it doesn't seem to hide it. it's here: http://cielprince.tumblr.com

Comment: You put it at the top right :P The rest of the code I will look at. `#top { position: fixed; top: 0px; right: 0px; z-index: -999px; }`

Comment: OK, I cannot find the JS code to go with the HTML I gave you... is it even there?

Comment: i actually added it to the wrong section of tumblr, it should be fixed now. Also, the code seems to work perfectly, i love it thank you so much! but is there a way to make it initially hidden? because when i load the page it seems to show up.

Comment: Do that in the CSS, add `display: none` to the rule for the ID selector.

Comment: One last note: `<div id="top"><a href="javascript:scroll(0,0)">Top</a></div>` remove the link (A tag) from this. or change the href to '#'. The js here is negating the animation. If you remove it the page will scroll to the top and no jump there.

Comment: fixed! AH! thank you so much for yourself! you are wonderful. :)

Comment: @Guchie based on your question I decided to write a plugin. http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/pk9aG/ - Maybe this will help you in the future.